# De-duplicating CSS

Tags: css, sass, gulp, themes

Our web application (Angular 1, Telerik Kendo, Bootstrap v4) has two themes: "light" and "dark".  We produce our CSS using SCSS equivalent to the following:

```
html {
    /* common css properties [snipped] */

    &.light {           
        @import "./kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.core.min";
        @import "./kendo/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min";

        @import "./variables.scss";
        @import "components.scss";          
    }

    &.dark {
        @import "./kendo/kendo.common-material.min";
        @import "./kendo/kendo.materialblack.min";

        @import "./variables-inverse.scss";
        @import "components.scss";
    }
}
```

We set a class on the `html` element to set the theme.  The site will *always* be "light" or "dark", nothing else.  This works perfectly well for us.  However, it also results in a lot of duplicated CSS rules, resulting in a larger-than-necessary CSS file.  A contrived example of what I mean:

```
html.light a { margin: 2em; }
html.dark a { margin: 2em; }
```

If the site is always "light" or "dark", these rules are effectively duplicates that can be simplified to:

```
a { margin: 2em; }
```

We use Gulp in our build process.

**Question**: How can I de-duplicate my CSS rules OR avoid duplicating them in the first place?

Comment: How is it not, if your sass is producing rubbish output, then you need to tidy it up the initial input - eg if you know that there are shared style that both templates use, then make a separate import at the top that splits out all the shared styles so you only have to add theme styles and overrides in your theme imports

Comment: Make a third css file with all the common properties and remove them from the other two.

Comment: I was hoping for a gulp plugin that might accomplish this.  It isn't an easy matter to separate out *by hand* all of the bootstrap rules.  I spent yesterday at that task but only a few Bootstrap components are completely identical.  Color isn't the only thing that varies.  And in the future, if we change a variable, the "duplicates" will change as well.

Comment: But in your example of 2 anchors, how would a plugin know that all anchors require that margin as both anchors have been pre-qualified?  Plugins would only be able to match selectors and then minify them based on that.  Besides reuquesting tools / plugins is off topic for this site

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Pre-qualified?

Comment: `html.light a` and `html.dark a` != `a` - how would a plugin know that you want all `a`s to have margin 2em when there is no rule for a standalone `a` in this

Comment: Every anchor must necessarily exist within either `html.light` or `html.dark`.  Every anchor is a descendant of `html`.

Comment: Yeah but a plugin doesn't know that is my point, if it did, it would probably because of some considerable config file in which case you may as well just change you initial sass

Comment: It won't unless its told, right.  I would expect a plugin capable of being configured.